# How to extract a number between two parenthesis in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a column `xyz` which has values like:

```
a(1)_f(5)_d(10)
a(12)_f(4)_d(3)
```

I need to extract and create new columns like this:

```
column a    column f   column d
1           5          10
12          4          3
```

Comment: one row with three columns...so for the above case i will have 2 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use [`split_part()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select split_part(split_part(col, ')', 1), '(', 2)::int as a,
       split_part(split_part(col, ')', 2), '(', 2)::int as f,
       split_part(split_part(col, ')', 3), '(', 2)::int as d
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=96412e9b6c79e64450ff98092e61cf1f)

```
SELECT
     vals[1]::int as a,
     vals[2]::int as f,
     vals[3]::int as d
FROM (
    SELECT
        regexp_matches(val, 'a\((\d+)\)_f\((\d+)\)_d\((\d+)\)') as vals
    FROM
        mytable
) s
```

Split the string with RegExp. The values can be put into groups `()`. All three groups can be called within the next step.

---

As stated in the comments, Redshift's support for regexp groups is really not the best, so tried to split the string with substring using position to find the delimiters:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=bb2dcc389e0be5114593665079d1fd4b)

```
SELECT
    substring(val, 3, position(')_f(' in val) - 3) as a,
    substring(val, position(')_f(' in val) + 4, position(')_d(' in val) - position(')_f(' in val) - 4),
    substring(val, position(')_d(' in val) + 4, length(val) - position(')_d(' in val) - 4)
FROM
    mytable
```

Comment: regexp_matches function does not exist in amazon redshift

Comment: @ShashikiranR Hm, does it work with `$1` instead of `\1`?

Comment: This isn't working too...i tried replacing with your new suggestions

Comment: @ShashikiranR ok, new approach using substring and position... It's really not very nice, but this should work in the end.